# jboss server start up error in liferay

Tags: liferay

```
14:03:35,576 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 14:03:35,575 ERROR [MSC service thread 1-2][MainServlet:217] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to deploy an older Liferay Portal version. Current build version is 6102 and attempting to deploy version 6101.
   14:03:35,578 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to deploy an older Liferay Portal version. Current build version is 6102 and attempting to deploy version 6101.
   14:03:35,580 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.upgrade(DBUpgrader.java:105)
   14:03:35,581 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:144)
   14:03:35,583 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:52)
   14:03:35,584 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1306)
   14:03:35,586 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:214)
   14:03:35,587 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
   14:03:35,588 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)
   14:03:35,590 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
   14:03:35,591 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655)
   14:03:35,592 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873)
   14:03:35,594 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
   14:03:35,595 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
   14:03:35,597 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
   14:03:35,599 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
   14:03:35,600 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
   14:03:35,602 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
   14:03:35,603 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) Stopping the server due to unexpected startup errors
   14:03:35,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
```

Comment: how about upgrading liferay

Comment: ask a question with proper explanation..

Comment: `Attempting to deploy an older Liferay Portal version. Current build version is 6102 and attempting to deploy version 6101.`

Answer (score 2):

This error has nothing to do with JBoss, but is triggered from Liferay during its' DB upgrade. You clearly try to deploy 6.1 GA2 using database where 6.1 GA3 was already installed (query Release_.buildnumber on your DB to check for version).